# htaccess rewrite error

Tags: .htaccess

What is wrong with this line

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?query=$1 [L]
```

I'm try rewrite links from

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?query=2012
```

to

```
http://mysite.com/2012
```

But i have **500 Internal Server Error**

Also here is the content from my htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^software$ index.php?type=app
RewriteRule ^movies$ index.php?type=movie
RewriteRule ^games$ index.php?type=game
RewriteRule ^music$ index.php?type=music
RewriteRule ^other$ index.php?type=other
RewriteRule ^tv$ index.php?type=tv-show
RewriteRule ^ebooks$ index.php?type=ebooks

RewriteRule ^(.*)-(\d+)\.html$ download.php?id=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^site/([^/]*)$ /index.php?site=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?query=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?query=$1 [L]
```

with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?query=$1 [L,QSA]
```